# UWP MVVM XAML Dynamic UserControl Manager

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, dynamic-usercontrols, xtype

I need help with a change of perspective.

I got stuck trying to approach UWP in a way I used to do in WPF regarding a MVVM pattern for managing UserControls dynamically.

I naturally tried to perform the same pattern in UWP but got stuck on various things like UWP not supporting 'x:Type' ...

Situation is; time to rethink this approach and look for a new direction. Seems I'm forced to abandon to use implicit binding in a similar fashion to the WPF pattern, using the *Content* property of a *ContentPresenter* and a VM property 'of type Object', which maintain a selected ViewModel. It was a simple and clean approach for matching up the correct View automagically with the VM set in ActiveViewModel.

the below was such a simple way of managing many views all over the place, odd MS not fixing this? But, back to the big Q: what now in UWP!?

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ActiveViewModel}">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:OneViewModel}">
            <local:OneView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TwoViewModel}">
            <local:TwoView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

What Shall I do instead of this!? Anyone found a new efficient way of doing it? I got stuck in my stubborn mind and need someone to kick my butt so I go forward. Getting to old to change, but due to this profession it seems I constantly have to. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate) documentation, there's a paragraph explaining the situation which you are trying to figure out.

> For advanced data binding scenarios, you might want to have properties
>   of the data determine which template should produce their UI
>   representations. For this scenario, you can use a DataTemplateSelector
>   and set properties such as ItemTemplateSelector to assign it to a data
>   view. A DataTemplateSelector is a logic class you write yourself,
>   which has a method that returns exactly one DataTemplate to the
>   binding engine based on your own logic interacting with your data. For
>   more info, see Data binding in depth.

[Here](http://www.teixeira-soft.com/bluescreen/2016/03/23/c-how-to-dinamicaly-select-a-datatemplate-for-each-item-in-a-list/), you have an example on how you can select distinct `DataTemplate` for items in a control such as a `ListView` based on defined conditions.

Your situation is a bit different from the one described above, but the solution should be within what is explained above.

- Create a class which derives from `DataTemplateSelector`, and override the `SelectTemplateCore` methods exposed by it, where you define the logic of what `DataTemplate` should be selected for the specific presented object.
- This Derived class should expose properties of type `DataTemplate`, which identify each single `DataTemplate` template object, you pretend to be able to choose from.
- Just as in the example, you are probably better of by defining the `DataTemplate` resources on an higher level object, such as the Page itself.
- Instantiate your `DataTemplateSelector` Derived class in XAML as a resource and set each of the properties exposed above of type DataTemplate to the analogous `DataTemplate` static resource.
- Utilize the `ContentTemplateSelector` dependency property, by setting it your custom DataTemplateSelector.

With this logic, it should be possible to have your `ContentPresenter` decide correctly between which `DataTemplate` it should choose from, based on your required UI logic.

Comment: André B Thanks, I'll have a look. I'm trying to find the most code neutral generic XAML (MVVM Friendly) oriented approach possible.  I have looked @tiago-teixeira 's solution previously as well as [link](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2017/03/25/uwp-implicit-data-template/) (Which I find the most pleasing so far ). your solution for sure solve some perspectives of the Challenge.

Comment: Sorry first time making comment on StackOverflow, but the link above is about using a _Converter_ in the _ContentTemplate_ property

Comment: First of all welcome to StackOverflow :) Yeah the link above is particularly interesting, but is a bit different than your specific case.
There isn't really as much information for these specific topic as there are for many others, which is rather unfortunate. Did you have any luck utilizing the ContentTemplateSelector dependency property?

Comment: Thanx! :) I have made a testshot regarding template selection (Based on the Converter), however I'm not so keen on his proposed x:Bind implementation . the WPF XAML in my example Binding and Presentation happens at the same time.  Here (in UWP) it's either Presentation or Binding. I was hoping for some magic bullet or someone saying.. NO no no, you are at it all wrong, do like this.. :)

Comment: André B, I set your suggestion as useful (I think that is the correct approach here - Tell me if you disagree). I decided to go with a slightly modified version of the Converter approach, suggested by Magnus.  It will suffice for my needs.  Thanks for your contribution and engagement, appreciated! Cheers.